# How to implement editor using QTextEdit with toolbar

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, editor, qtextedit

I'm looking for an example on how to implement a typical rich text editor using QTextEdit.

What I need to implement is a toolbar containing formating functions like:
- bold, underline, intalic
- font family, size
- foreground, background color
- text-alignment

Something like this is implemented in QtCreator in designer.

Thanks for advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tada! [the answer to your question](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/demos-textedit.html)

all you have to do is google, and study the code. if ever you are having difficulty with anything, please refer to Qt's documentation first before asking.

Comment: link is no longer working, but the demo can be found here: http://qt.apidoc.info/4.8.5/demos-textedit.html